# what software packages required to write applet to add to unity panel/bar

Tags: unity, gnome, sensors

I was recently frustrated to find that I could not add the gnome "sensors-applet" to the unity bar/panel along the top of the desktop.

Assuming somebody (like me perhaps) wanted to modify an applet like "sensors-applet" (made for gnome desktop) so it could be added to the unity bar/panel, what source-code and/or libraries would I need to write/modify such software?

Could I do something like this by [more-or-less] finding an applet that can be added to the unity bar/panel, rip out that part of the code that puts the icon on the panel, then graft that onto the original "sensors-applet" in place of the equivalent gnome panel code?  Or is this idea totally naive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think appindicator is what you are looking for http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm reading the documentation to learn more.  One question though.  Why doesn't someone create an open standard so all future bar/panel applets run on every bar/panel of every future desktop?  It seems a shame that all sorts of really great applets become useless just because someone reinvents the bar/panel interface every 2 or 3 years.

Comment: The app was probably built as a gnome panel applet instead of an indicator. I don't know why they didn't offer some sort of a compatibility layer to bring exsisting panel applets to unity and gnome 3 but I'm sure they have their reasons why.